# Degree of freedom and corrected standard deviation

Tags: statistics

It is often said that degree of freedom causes the need for standard deviation formula to be corrected. When explaining degree of freedom, it is often said that when one knows the mean of the formula, only $n-1$ data are actually needed, as the last data can be determined using mean and $n-1$ data. However, I see the same thing occuring in population - not just in sample. So what's going on here, and how is this justification really working?

For example, in simple linear regression model, variance of error terms are often sum of variance of each data divided by $n-2$. This is justified as said above. But if this justification is also true for population, not just sample, how is this really working?

Comment: Dividing by $n-1$ gives an unbiased estimator of the variance. However, in the case of the normal, dividing by $n$ gives an estimator which, though biased, is "on average" closer to the truth. At the practical level, it doesn't matter, since very small samples are of little use.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the sample points $X_i$'s are iid normal then $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ follows $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distribution where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean while $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2$ follows $\chi^2_n$ distribution, where $\mu$ is the population mean. The suffix of $\chi^2$ is named as the degrees of freedom of the chi square distribution. That is the significance of the term degrees of freedom. As expectation of a $\chi^2_{\nu}$ random variable is $\nu$, $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$,population variance, whereas $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2$ is the unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$.

Similarly $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{\beta}_0-\hat{\beta}_1x_i)^2$ follows $\chi^2_{n-2}$ distribution under the assumption that the errors are iid $N(0,1)$ where $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$ are the sample estimates of the regression coefficients whereas  $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-{\beta}_0-{\beta}_1x_i)^2$ follows $\chi^2_{n}$ distribution where $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are population regression coefficients.